# Find unknown $5\times 5$ matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I am looking for a way to find a $5\times 5$ matrix. The matrix is used to transform colors in a photo. The matrix transforms red, green, blue, and opacity values into new values like this :
$$\begin{pmatrix}R'\\G'\\B'\\A'\\1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}r1&r2&r3&r4&r5\\
g1&g2&g3&g4&g5\\
b1&b2&b3&b4&b5\\
a1&a2&a3&a4&a5\\
0&0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}R\\G\\B\\A\\1\end{pmatrix}$$

The last line of the matrix has know values and the effect I am looking for doesn't include opacity changes so $A'$ and $A$ are always equal to 1.

The effect I need on images is already made with an image editing software but I need to find this matrix to use it in an [SVG filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feColorMatrix). I can therefore identify $R', G', B', A'$ and $R,G,B, A$ for many color transformations.

The issue is that I cannot identify the unknow values in the matrix as each time I set the equations, I end up with too many uknowns.

Is it even possible to find the values of the $5\times 5$ matrix ?

*This is a follow up question from this stackoverflow post : [Convert photoshop adjustement layer to SVG filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77459439/convert-photoshop-adjustement-layer-to-svg-filter)*

Comment: Are you asking whether the matrix can be recovered from the vectors $\pmatrix{R'&G'&B'&A'&1}$ and $\pmatrix{R&G&B&A&1}$? In that case, certainly not---the resulting system contains 20 unknowns ($r_1, \ldots, a_5$) but only $4$ equations. If you have several pairs of such vectors all transformed using the same matrix, you can typically recover the matrix.

Comment: @TravisWillse I can have many pairs of in and out vectors that are transformed using the same (unknown) matrix.

Comment: Do you know what linear independence of a set of vectors is? A linearly independent set of $5$ input vectors together with their outputs is enough to determine the matrix, as in Vladimir Lysikov's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Take $5$ random RGBA values $R_k, G_k, B_k, A_k$ for $k = 1,2,3,4,5$ and record the corresponding values $R'_k, G'_k, B'_k, A'_k$ after the application of the filter. We have
$$\begin{bmatrix} R'_1 & R'_2 & R'_3 & R'_4 & R'_5 \\ G'_1 & G'_2 & G'_3 & G'_4 & G'_5 \\ B'_1 & B'_2 & B'_3 & B'_4 & B'_5 \\ A'_1 & A'_2 & A'_3 & A'_4 & A'_5 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = M \cdot \begin{bmatrix} R_1 & R_2 & R_3 & R_4 & R_5 \\ G_1 & G_2 & G_3 & G_4 & G_5 \\ B_1 & B_2 & B_3 & B_4 & B_5 \\ A_1 & A_2 & A_3 & A_4 & A_5 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$ where $M$ is out unknown matrix. $M$ can now be recovered as
$$M = \begin{bmatrix} R'_1 & R'_2 & R'_3 & R'_4 & R'_5 \\ G'_1 & G'_2 & G'_3 & G'_4 & G'_5 \\ B'_1 & B'_2 & B'_3 & B'_4 & B'_5 \\ A'_1 & A'_2 & A'_3 & A'_4 & A'_5 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} R_1 & R_2 & R_3 & R_4 & R_5 \\ G_1 & G_2 & G_3 & G_4 & G_5 \\ B_1 & B_2 & B_3 & B_4 & B_5 \\ A_1 & A_2 & A_3 & A_4 & A_5 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}^{-1}$$

If you do not care about opacity, then the fourth row of $M$ is $0, 0, 0, 0, 1$ and the fourth column is $0$, the rest can be found analogously as
$$\begin{bmatrix} r_1 & r_2 & r_3 & r_5 \\ g_1 & g_2 & g_3 & g_5 \\ b_1 & b_2 & b_3 & b_5 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} R'_1 & R'_2 & R'_3 & R'_4 \\ G'_1 & G'_2 & G'_3 & G'_4 \\ B'_1 & B'_2 & B'_3 & B'_4 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} R_1 & R_2 & R_3 & R_4 \\ G_1 & G_2 & G_3 & G_4  \\ B_1 & B_2 & B_3 & B_4 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}^{-1}$$

Comment: Thanks a ton ! I now need to find color values that let me make an invertible matrix. I will test this extensively.

Comment: The simplest choice, if possible is to just test the action of the matrix on a set of basis vectors, the obvious choice being one vector each of all red, green, and blue.